# Saving families out vie Revit API

Tags: revit-api, revit

while collecting all the families in a project and saving them out via the API,

```
familyDocument.SaveAs(fileName);
```

Is there a way to catch the following dialogue box and perform an action?  For instance, record the warning and close the dialogue box?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Revit API offers two different mechanisms to react to and handle dialogue and failure messages: the [DialogBoxShowing event](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/cb46ea4c-2b80-0ec2-063f-dda6f662948a.htm) and the [Failure API](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/d0795bd6-f092-90f2-5c2c-3876e616454c.htm). If all of these fail, a third mechanism is provided by the Windows API, which enables hooking into and reacting to almost any system event, including a dialogue showing. All three approaches are discussed and compared by The Building Coder in the topic group on [Detecting and Handling Dialogues and Failures](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.32).